# syntax highlighting with jquery not working

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I can't figure out why this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469402/binding-jquery-event-on-ajax-callback) I have on SO doesn't do syntax highlighting. Usually I don't have to do anything as long as I've got the tag in place (in this case jquery). I've also tried:

`<script language=javascript>`

`<!-- language: lang-js -->`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like it's highlighting keywords

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your language comment was being ignored because there wasn't another line between that and the first `<script>` element you had there, so that entire piece was being removed as bad HTML, and it was interpreting the code as HTML because of the second, opening `<script>` tag.

Without the language comment, it's interpreted as HTML because it starts with an HTML opening tag. You could just remove the surrounding `<script>` tags and it should highlight as normal code.

Comment: Thanks, that was bothering me!